# How to build building that is made of small pieces - how to correctly put rigid body over rigid body?

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation

I'm new to blender and actually amazed from the possibilities it provides. I successfully created a set of boxes (like domino tiles) that fall in a chain reaction. (Like in this answer: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/7111/8260).
When I did this there was a tiny fall of the tiles (about 0.001cm) and very quickly they stood still.

OK, Now I want to build a +30 tiles height building (and see them fall :-) ), but even though I put the tile one over another with precise mathematical positioning they still have an initial shake, so a 5 floor tower stands, but a high tower just falls by itself.

The tower I am tring to build looks like this:
*(this is an example of 5 floor tower, each floor has 2 vertical tiles and one horizontal)*

```
__
||
__
||
__
||
__
||
__
||
```

So my question is - how can I position this kind of building with 30 floors or more without get the "initial shake" when starting the simulation - I want the building to fall only when it gets hit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AFAIK Bullet (the library blender uses for rigid body simulations) is designed more for real-time speed over accuracy, so you might have to use some tricks.

1. Select all the objects in the tower and enable *Enable Deactivation* and *Start Deactivated* in *Properties > Physics > Rigid Body Collisions*.

   [image]

   Then right click on each setting and select *Copy to selected*.

   This will make it so the tower will not be simulated until another active rigid body comes near it.
2. Increase the number of simulation steps in *Properties > Scene > Rigid Body World*:

   [image]

   The higher this value is, the more CPU time is needed to calculate the simulation. However, higher values will also make the simulation more accurate.

### [Result](http://gfycat.com/SnappyOptimalFirefly):

[image]

Comment: Great answer. Also, i can't stop watching the gif @.@.

Comment: @StarWeaver lol There is also a smooth video version if you click on it (the gif) ;)