# Prevent rigid bodies used as particles from going through each other

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

I'm a student looking at microstructures of foods. I created an 'emulsion', but the droplets 'go through' each other. See image.
[image]
The image shows a rendered slice of a box filled with balls (after simulation). This slice is very thin (0.02 in BU), so the overlap is not caused by different depth of the balls.

Does anyone know how to solve this? The balls are rigid bodies in a particle system.

Jantine

Rigid Body and collision settings for the 'source' object for the particles system:
[image]

(Collision shape is convex hull).
Substeps:

[image]

Collision shape is set to sphere. Increasing steps/s causes no difference. Result:
[image]

The spheres go less deep through each other, but the problem is still there. If anyone has a suggestion...?

The bounciness of the spheres during animation are quite high, although these are Rigid Bodies. During animation:
[image]

Comment: Give us your rigid body settings - what collision shape you use, and your solver settings (how many steps/s and iterations does it use).

Comment: [Related](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7087/how-to-make-small-objects-fall-properly-with-rigid-body) The choice of the BU size is arbitrary, and can be converted to a length unit using the scene unit scale settings.  Using such small sizes could I believe, lead to precision errors. If the height of the slice above is 0.02  then your smallest droplets are 0.001 or less. Have you tried using a bigger size? maybe 2 bu for the slice, and droplet sizes scaled accordingly.

Comment: I've already tried bigger sizes. But also without cross-section it is already visible that the spheres go through each other.

Comment: Where  can I find the solver settings? (which tab/panel?)

Comment: @Jan I guess Jerry means the Rigid Body World which is Found in *Properties Panel > Scene*

Comment: You definitely need to use Sphere as the collision shape, it is the most accurate (for spheres). Yes the rigid body world settings, you can increase the steps to increase accuracy.